# Do you get punished in Deus Ex Mankind Divided for keeping the main quest waiting?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

I'm early in the game, and there's a bunch of sidequests I'd like to go progress, but I'm getting supposedly urgent missions from my police boss.  Can those wait while I go explore?

Answer (score 4):

You do not get punished as I did all of my side missions first and only then main ones. I kept my main guys waiting for a long time, (I did some of them in parallel though, but why wouldn't you if you are nearby).

> At one point you get to choose which mission to do (Save the girl or rob the bank) and they both are urgent but this is intentional choice you have to make and then 'other' mission gets failed.

If you are worried about not being allowed to finish side missions, before changing the continent they give you warning that you will be leaving area and all unfinished missions will be abandoned.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't know for sure that you weren't punished.  In Human Revolution it was not immediately obvious just how badly you had been punished for not proceeding to the first mission right away.  Only by reading online did I realize what my delay had cost.  (Admittedly, it's hard to see how delaying could have affected anything in the first couple of missions of Mankind Divided.  But we'll never know until someone tries both ways.)